# mobilesubstrate extension

Tags: ios

I'm just starting my research on a system-wide keyboard replacement app, but I'm having trouble determining if I need to jailbreak my iPhone in order to use mobilesubstrate extension.

Does anyone know the answer to this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can find another way to alter the keyboard system-wide **without jailbreaking** you've got a bright future ahead of you.

**So yea, you do need to jailbreak your device to accomplish this. MobileSubstrate is only available through Cydia — which requires jailbreaking.**

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I am coming to the same conclusion.

Comment: Actually even with a jailbroken device if you can write a system wide keyboard replacement you have a bright future ahead of yourself. When developing SwipeSelection I found out just how complex the keyboard is on iOS, and how deeply it's ingrained into UIKit.

Comment: There are a lot of third-party system wide input methods in Chinese.Actually I'm the one of the developers. : P